# Check if string is a valid URL

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to write a program or function that checks if a string is a valid URL.

Given a string as input, you will output a truthy value if the input is a valid URL. If it is not, output a falsey value. An input string is considered a valid URL if all of the following criteria are met:

- Begins with `http://` or `https://`
- At least one and up to 128 labels (parts of URL delimited by a period)

  - Labels delimited by a period
  - Contain only letters, digits, and hyphens
  - Do not start nor end with a hyphen
  - Third and fourth characters cannot be a hyphen, unless the first two characters are 'xn'
  - A label may contain zero to 63 characters
- The length of the string does not exceed 253 characters

This is a code-golf, with standard rules.

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, nice first question. When posting next question use sandbox https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1

Comment: A full URL may have many more components than just the scheme and the host: `scheme://user:password@host:port/path?query#fragment`, to say nothing of schemes other than `http`/`https` with their own different URL syntax, or `http`/`https` URLs for a literal IPv6 address rather than a hostname. Since you seem to be primarily interested in validating the hostname part, I’d recommend letting the challenge be “check if a string is a valid hostname” and removing the `scheme://` entirely.

Comment: Also, if you read the standard (RFC 952, RFC 1034, RFC 1123, RFC 3696, RFC 5891) rather than Wikipedia: a label cannot be empty; the restriction on the total length is not 253 but rather 255 minus the number of labels; the top-level (last) label may not be all-numeric; and the restriction about the third and fourth characters not being a hyphen refers to the decoded Unicode string represented by an IDN label, not its encoded ASCII representation (and there are many other Unicode-related restrictions that you probably don’t want to think about).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg The question doesn't necessarily have to use real URLs. The question could just as well be called "Check if the string is a valid [some made-up word]" where [some made-up word] is defined with the above criteria.

Comment: Please add some test cases.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 114 bytes

```
x=>RegExp(`^(?!.*([./](-|(?!xn)[^/]{2}--)|-[./]|-$))https?://${a='[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,63}'}(?:\\.${a}){0,127}`).test(x)
```

Hopes it works.

For *real* URLs, you should use:

```
x=>eval(`try{new URL(x)}catch(e){}`)
```

Thanks to ThePirateBay, construct regex from string save 3 bytes.